# send form data to admin email in codeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I am newer for codeigniter. I have an one contact form with fields of stream, name, email, contact. But I have an problem with form data are not send to admin email. When i tried to submit the data on contact form page source will alert but i have given other alert data.
I have tried following code,

```js
$('#interiorid').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       var interiorstream = $('#interiorstream').val();
        var interiorname = $('#interiorname').val();
         var interiormobile = $('#interiormobile').val();
        var interioremail = $('#interioremail').val();
        var mobileVarify = /[0-9]/.test(interiormobile);
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

var dataString = 'interiorstream =' +  interiorstream + '&interiorname =' + interiorname + '&interiormobile =' + interiormobile + '&interioremail =' + interioremail;
 

alert(interiorstream);        
if (interiorstream == "0") {
            alert('Please select Stream');
        }
        else {
            if (interiorname.length > 2) {
                if (mobileVarify == true && interiormobile.length == 10) {
                    if (regex.test(interioremail) == true) {
                        $.ajax({
                             url: 'interior_email',
                            type: 'post',
                           data: dataString,
                            success: function (msg, status) {
  alert(status);
  alert(msg);
                                $("#interiorid")[0].reset();
                                window.location.href = "/contact/thank-you";
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Invalid Email');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    alert('Invalid Number');
                }
            }
            else {
                alert('Please enter name');
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<!--- View ---->
<form id="interiorid">
                                <div class="form-div">
                                    <select value="" id="interiorstream" >
                                        <option value="0">Select a Stream</option>
                                        <option value="Interior Designing">Interior Designing</option>
                                        <option value="Fashion Designing">Fashion Designing</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-div">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="interiorname">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-div">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" id="interiormobile">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-div">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="interioremail">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-div">
                                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                                </div>
                            </form>

<!----Controller ---->

<?php

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->load->helper(array('url'));
 
    }

    function index() {

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('home');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        $this->load->helper('form'); 
         $this->load->view('interior/interior-intro'); 
    }

  

  
 function interior_email()
{
  if (!isset($_POST['e-mail'])){
      //redirect if no parameter e-mail
      redirect(base_url());
    }else{
        $interiorstream = $this->input->post('interiorstream');
        $interiorname = $this->input->post('interiorname');
        $interiorphone = $this->input->post('interiorphone');
        $interioremail = $this->input->post('interioremail');

        $message = 'Hello Admin, This mail received from Interior design page contact form.<br/><br/>
                Stream:' . $interiorstream . '<br/><br/>
                Name :' . $interiorname . '<br/><br/>
                Contact :' . $interiorphone . '<br><br>
  Email :' . $interioremail;
        

        $headers1 = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "To:";
        $headers1 .= "example.com <info@example.com>";
        $headers1 .= "\r\n";
        $headers1 .= 'From: INIFD : info@example.com' . "\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "\r\n";
        $subject = "Enquiry From example.com Web";
        $email = 'admin@example.com';
       
        if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers1)) {
         echo 'mail has been sent';
            } else {
                echo 'mail sending failed';
            }
 }
      }

}
?>
```

wrong popup like this:

[image]

So please help me.

Comment: @RaxShah But my other page contact form working

Comment: @RaxShah Other form also with Mail() function.

Comment: @RaxShah when i click on submit button, it execute one alert box but not with actual data. I t alerts wrong data.

Comment: @RaxShah But when mail executed I want to redirected to than you page. Also ajax success function are not giving proper data.

Comment: @RaxShah How to put redirect code in controller

Comment: @RaxShah I have added screen shot of that alert box

Comment: @RaxShah Please provide any other solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120408/discussion-between-dnyan-and-rax-shah).

Comment: You might want to check $message, there is no closing ' on the first line. The same goes for Email :' . $interioremail

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are running on a localhost, it is near impossible to send emails. You can check this is if you really want to send [Check this post out](https://www.google.com.gh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwicq_iztbHOAhXCvhQKHVppA8MQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codexworld.com%2Fhow-to-send-email-from-localhost-in-php%2F&usg=AFQjCNGIn0eaWAgfDiFxnmsCnjDLR2dPmw&bvm=bv.129391328,d.d24) or try PHPMailer

Comment: Please provide any other solutions